# Small/toy language compiler/interpreter implemented in Java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, interpreter

I'm looking for a small/toy programming language that is implemented in Java. The implementation should preferably not be much more than around a 1000 lines or so. It might e.g. be a simple imperative language, an expression parser/interpreter or something similar. The intention is to use it as an example for a paper I'm writing, and while I could mock up something myself, it would be better to be able to refer to something that already exists. Thanks!

Comment: You may check this: https://github.com/loki2302/jsick-app

Answer (score 2):

It's not so small as to be called a "toy" but Andrew Appel's Tiger language (from the book *[Modern Compiler Implementation in Java](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/)* was designed to teach the basics and has a reference implementation:

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/project.html

Answer (score 1):

If a [Lexical Analyzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) is okay for you, check [JLex](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/JLex/)

Comment: A lexer is only 10% of a language implementation.

Comment: delnan: Yes, but I just thought it would be useful. And it's not too off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would really like some actual language implementations though, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if my suggestion is on time. In Russian we say 'spoon is worth during lunch time only'.

But anyway, if you still interested you might consider [IUMLS](http://code.google.com/p/iumls/).

Thanks.